# ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

Hi Today I added a SSL certificate for a ASP.NET website.

After adding the certificate I am getting ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY error

If I access site using http its working but https its giving the error
[Application hosted in Windows server 2016 and IIS 10]

Comment: it could have many reasons, but i had this issue before and i uninstall my antivirus(kaspersky) and the problem solved. cause it blocked my **ssl certificate**

Comment: @nima ansari there is no anti virus installed in my server.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Kestrel server to serve Http1. Please follow the following instruction to solve the problem -

1. Go to your project appsettings.json file.
2. Add below code under  "AllowedHosts": "*" line

   "Kestrel": {
   "EndpointDefaults": {
   "Protocols": "Http1"
   }
   }

Your default appsettings.json file will look like this -

```
{
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*",
   "Kestrel": {
      "EndpointDefaults": {
         "Protocols": "Http1"
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable HTTP2 and try it again:

1. Start → regeditEditor
2. Navigate to the folder/path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
3. Under the Parameters folder, right-click the white-space, add 2 new
   DWORD (32-bit) values:

   - EnableHttp2Tls
   - EnableHttp2Cleartext
4. Ensure both new values have been set to 0(disabled) by
   right-clicking the value and clicking "Modify..."
5. Restart the OS.

[image]

Comment: Should I add it in my Server

Comment: In your regeditEditor. You can check the image in my answer above.