# Swagger UI is not working in localhost only on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger-ui

After upgrading to .NET SDK 8 and encountering issues with your IDE, you decided to uninstall it and instead install .NET 7. However, after doing so, Swagger UI, which was previously working, stopped functioning. It's worth noting that other developers are still able to access the UI without any problems.

When attempting to access the Swagger UI, you receive the following error message:

"This site can't be reached
The webpage at https://localhost:8080/swagger might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY"

Meanwhile, my application itself is running fine.

I tried to launch the application to use Swagger UI and expected to get the Swagger UI web page.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066350/err-http2-inadequate-transport-security ?

Comment: adding    "Kestrel": {
      "EndpointDefaults": {
         "Protocols": "Http1"
      }
   } 
to appsettings.json 
worked for me